# Painting inner circle with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can someone explain why the inner circle is being painted? My code make circles and when it completes 360 degree it paints the whole canvas again. I thought it would only paint balls on the border of the new circle. Just to let it more clear (maybe). I would like to paint only the circles and not the center of the movemente. The Idea was to form a contour on the circle's movement with the balls and make a new one, every 360 degree (the reason why I call drawStage).
images of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF8fJ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSRHS.jpg

the part that I painted red is the problem

HTML CODE (tela.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>JS Game</title>
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Game</h1>
<canvas id="tela"></canvas>

<script src="Game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript code (Game.js)

```
console.log("Starting Game");
var canvas = document.querySelector('#tela');
var stageCollor = 'black';
var ballColor = 'grey';
console.log(canvas);
var stage = canvas.getContext('2d');
var ball = canvas.getContext('2d');
drawStage();
let distanceFromCenter = 0;
let startWidth = canvas.width/2;
let startHeight = canvas.height/2;
let ballRadius = 10;
let startAngle = 0;
let endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
let turnedAngle = 0;
let piTurnedAngle= 0;
ball.arc(startWidth, startHeight, ballRadius, startAngle, endAngle);
ball.stroke();//draw
ball.fillStyle = ballColor;
ball.lineWidth = 1;
ball.fill();

setInterval(move,40);//magic

function move() {
    //drawStage();
    turnedAngle = turnedAngle +5;
    piTurnedAngle = turningMovement(turnedAngle);
    distanceFromCenter = distanceFromCenter +0.0125;
    startWidth = startWidth + distanceFromCenter*Math.cos(piTurnedAngle);
    startHeight = startHeight - distanceFromCenter*Math.sin(piTurnedAngle);
    drawBall();
}

function drawBall() {   
    ball.arc(startWidth, startHeight, ballRadius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ball.stroke();//draw
    ball.fillStyle = ballColor;
    ball.lineWidth = 1;
    ball.fill();
    console.log('d - ' + startWidth);
}

function eraseBall() {  
    ball.arc(startWidth, startHeight, ballRadius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ball.stroke();//draw
    ball.fillStyle = stageCollor;
    ball.lineWidth = 1;
    ball.fill();
    console.log('e - ' + startWidth);
}

function drawStage(){
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 600;
    stage.fillStyle = stageCollor;
    stage.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    stage.beginPath();
}

function turningMovement(angle){
    if(angle>360){
        angle = angle%360;
        if (angle == 0){
            drawStage();
        }
    }
    newAngle = angle/180;
    newAngle = newAngle*Math.PI;
    return newAngle;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you elaborate on what you want to happen? Is the ball supposed to be repeatedly stamped or should it appear to move? The reason you're clearing the screen on each full rotation is because `drawStage()` is called whenever `angle == 0` inside of `turningMovement(angle)`. `stage.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)` dumps black on the entire canvas inside of `drawStage`. The code abuses globals and is difficult to follow--I recommend a round of cleanup. Use parameters and make functions pure.

Comment: Also, trying to erase a ball with your `erase` function is probably not going to work. It's better to wipe the whole screen and re-draw all entities on every frame, counterintuitive as it may seem.

Comment: I let that function there but I gave up on "erase". Sorry I should have removed this function.

Comment: No problem. If you describe your desired behavior, I can write you an answer.

Comment: I would like to paint only the ball and not the center of the movement. it should be black(center of the stage), grey (circle make with balls) and black again (stage). but for some reason (I don't know) the center of the stage is being painted.

Comment: OK, so in other words it should look like a single ball is making increasingly large spiraling rotations with no trail? Right now, it's leaving a trail and painting as it goes.

Comment: No I want the trail that the ball make. The problem is the trail that is not make by the ball itself. I will see if I can show pictures of my problem. Maybe 2 pictures may explain better.

Comment: The part that I painted with the red collor is my problem. I don't know why my program is painting it. https://imgur.com/Iaj4pfv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the canvas is filling up the path drawn between various balls. You periodically call `arc()` within `drawBall()`, but you never call `beginPath()` or `endPath()`.

This is the simplest example I can think of (using your JS code) to illustrate the problem: remove the `setInterval()` line so that the animation does not start. Then run the following in console:

```
drawStage();
turnedAngle = 10; startWidth = 404.45625508238027; startHeight = 299.2142419960571; drawBall();
turnedAngle = 70; startWidth = 423.114564032465; startHeight = 280.45069066017015; drawBall();
turnedAngle = 150; startWidth = 408.03409582988786; startHeight = 248.52411884675797; drawBall();
```

Note the triangle being drawn across the 3 balls.

To solve this, simply add `ball.beginPath()` before your `arc()` call.